# Más de lo normal / Más que lo normal

Tags: preposiciones

¿Debería usar "que" o "de" en los siguientes contextos?

> Estos días estoy más cansado de/que lo normal.
>
> Últimamente, he trabajado más de/que lo normal.

Pienso que debería ser "que" porque es una comparación, pero no tengo respaldo gramatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En las comparaciones se usa "que"; sin embargo, lo usual es "de lo normal" y no "que lo normal".

Cuando se compara con "lo normal", se usa "de" como caso excepcional. Toda comparación con lo normal, como "más cansado de lo normal" convierte el significado en "especialmente cansado", lo que no ocurre en otras comparaciones.

Comment: ¿Podrías citar una fuente?

Comment: En [este blog de español para polacos](http://castellano.blox.pl/2009/02/Comparaciones-msmenos-de-vs-msmenos-que.html) y en [esta página de español para finalndeses](http://users.jyu.fi/~torremor/cursos/gramatica/042.html) se estudian los distintos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes toda la razón al estar comparando deberás de usar el pronombre qué, ya que implíctamente te señala a tí como el sustantivo (sujeto) que realiza una acción que es comparada con el resto de las personas, en cambio de solo es una preposición que se debe utilizar para otras ocasiones como denotar lugar, composición, tiempo, posesión, etc.

Comment: Creo que en realidad depende de a que te quieras referir si te refieres a "lo normal" como lo que tú normalmente haces si deberías usar "que", pero si te refieres a "lo normal" como lo que haces el común de las personas, si deberías usar "de".

Comment: ¿Podrías citar una fuente?